# Role of noise in ACGAN

Tags: python, deep-learning

I have been experimenting with GAN and ACGAN.

The ACGAN I'm experimenting with is for generating MNIST images. It takes both noise and a digit label; embeds the label; multiplies that with noise and uses it to generate an image of that digit label.

I wanted to see what happens if I pass only digit labels to an ACGAN for generating MNIST images (essentially I made the noise as all 1). The network still generated digit images but it took more time to generate them; and they were not as good as the ones from earlier ACGAN.

So obviously noise is important in generating good images; but what's the intuitive reasoning behind its importance? The noise is random, so how can it contribute to generating images that we pre-specify?

Here's the original ACGAN I experimented with: https://github.com/eriklindernoren/Keras-GAN/blob/master/acgan/acgan.py

Answer (score 1):

The noise is used to provide a variation in outputs; Without any random noise you should get only one output image per class input.